# Game-Server running on local machine but not on ubuntu server

Tags: c#, server, system.net

My Server (System.Net) is working on my local mashine (win10), but not on the ubuntu server, i get this error:

```
Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. (Parameter 'size')
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.BeginRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at Server.Client.Start() in C:\Users\xxxx\source\repos\Server\Server\Client.cs:line 28
   at Server.ClientManager.CreateNewConnection(TcpClient tempClient) in C:\Users\xxxx\source\repos\Server\Server\ClientManager.cs:line 19
   at Server.Server.OnClientConnect(IAsyncResult result) in C:\Users\xxxx\source\repos\Server\Server\Server.cs:line 61
   at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
   at System.Net.ContextAwareResult.CompleteCallback()
   at System.Net.ContextAwareResult.<>c.<Complete>b__15_0(Object s)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.ContextAwareResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
   at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(Object result, IntPtr userToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.BaseOverlappedAsyncResult.CompletionCallback(Int32 numBytes, SocketError errorCode)
   at System.Net.Sockets.AcceptOverlappedAsyncResult.CompletionCallback(IntPtr acceptedFileDescriptor, Byte[] socketAddress, Int32 socketAddressLen, SocketError errorCode)
   at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncContext.AcceptOperation.InvokeCallback(Boolean allowPooling)
   at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncContext.OperationQueue`1.ProcessAsyncOperation(TOperation op)
   at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncContext.ReadOperation.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.Execute()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
Aborted (core dumped)
```

this is the code thats causing the error (its working on my local):

```
socket.SendBufferSize = 4096;
socket.ReceiveBufferSize = 4096;
stream = socket.GetStream();
recBuffer = new byte[4096];
stream.BeginRead(recBuffer, 0, socket.ReceiveBufferSize, OnReceiveData, null);
Console.WriteLine($"Connection from {socket.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString()}");
```

when i listen with netcat to the port im using (55555) and connect in the game, the connection works, so i think the port/firewall is fine.

i tried exporting it as a linux build, and as a windows build, which i executed via wine, both didn't work.

this is how i published it:
[publish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4l6I.png)